# How to construct a data frame from raw data from a CSV file

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am currently learning the python environment to process sensor data.

I have a board with 32 sensors reading temperature. At the following link, you can find an extract of the raw data: https://5e86ea3db5a86.htmlsave.net/

I am trying to construct a data frame grouped by date from my CSV file using pandas (see the potential structure of the table https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zpDI7tp4nSn8-Hm3T_xd4Xz7MV6VDGcWGxwNO-8S0-s/edit?usp=sharing

So far, I have read the data file in pandas and delete all the unnamed columns. I am struggling with the creation of a column sensor ID which should contain the 32 sensor ID and the column temperature.

How should I loop through this CSV file to create 3 columns (date, sensor ID and temperature)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first item in each line is the date, then there are pairs of sensor id and value, then a blank value that we can exclude. If so, then the following should work. If not, try to modify the code to your purposes.

```
data = []

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # the if excludes empty strings
        parts = [part for part in line.split(',') if part]

        # this gets the date in a format that pandas can recognize
        # you can omit the replace operations if not needed
        sensor_date = parts[0].strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

        # the rest of the list are the parings of sensor and reading
        sensor_readings = parts[1:]

        # this uses list slicing to iterate over even and odd elements in list
        # ::2 means every second item starting with zero, which are evens
        # 1::2 means every second item starting with one, which are odds
        for sensor, reading in zip(sensor_readings[::2], sensor_readings[1::2]):
            data.append({'sensor_date': sensor_date, 
                         'sensor': sensor, 
                         'reading': reading})

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Using your sample data, I got the following:

```
=== Output: ===
Out[64]:
                      sensor_date            sensor  reading
0    Tue Jul 02 16:35:22.782 2019  28C037080B000089  16.8750
1    Tue Jul 02 16:35:22.782 2019  284846080B000062  17.0000
2    Tue Jul 02 16:35:22.782 2019  28A4BA070B00002B  16.8750
3    Tue Jul 02 16:35:22.782 2019  28D4E3070B0000D5  16.9375
4    Tue Jul 02 16:35:22.782 2019  28A21E080B00002F  17.0000
..                            ...               ...      ...
```